# Can I change texture of a mesh with the command line?

Tags: texturing, command-line

I know it is possible to render a 3D model with blender's command line interface, but is it possible to also change the texture?

Comment: If you write a script in Python to change the texture, you can execute that from the command line with `blender -b <file> -P <script>`

Comment: @ScottMilner that means it is also possible to add a mesh to a coordinate of a scene with blender CLI

Comment: Yes. Anything you can do without GUI input in Python can be done with the command line.

Comment: As far as giving input to the script goes, (i.e. to select a texture), you can give arguments to `sys.argv` with `blender -b <file> -P <script> -- arg1 arg2 argn`.